# Nuget manager not prompting credentials while connecting to artifactory

Tags: nuget-package

I am using VS2017, when i tried to open Package manager and selecting Artifactory as package source its not prompting for credentials and returning

[Artifactory] The V2 feed at 'https://itec-artifactory-.....' returned an unexpected status code '403 Forbidden'.

I tried clearing nuget and browser cache, but it didn't work.

The same scenario in VS 2013, its prompting for credentials and connected successfully.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Any help?

Answer (score 10):

Reset the Nuget artifactory credentials. They are stored in Control Panel -> Credential Manager.

Go to Windows credentials. Remove with "VSCredentials_" prefix.

Restart VS.